# check table and foreign key table check

Tags: sap-data-dictionary

The system correctly set the foreign key (zemploy01-department) with the check table (zdepartmentt02-department) - inside the red box in the diagram. If i do a system check, the system says: **zemploy01-department is consistant.**

It is apparent that the system takes all primary keys from the check table, and tries to match it to the keys of the foreign key table. The primary key columns of check table(zdepartmentt02) are: MANDT, CAREER, DEPARTMENT, LANGUAGE. These are matched to MANDT, CAREER, DEPARTMENT columns of the foreign key table(zemploy01). **However, only one column should be matched i.e. zdepartmentt02-department and zemploy01-department.** Why is the system trying to match all the primary keys of the check table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not? What do you already know about foreign keys and referential integrity?

Comment: take a look at zdepartmentt02 table and you'll figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

The values filled in on this wizard are the fields you have set as primary keys in the check table